# Working with two CSV files, taking column values from one and using it on the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two CSV files and am using pandas to compare them:

The profiles.csv has the following info:

```
first_name, last_name, gender
john, smith, 
jane, belle,
peter, parker
```

The name_gender.csv has the following info:

```
first_name, last_name
peter, male
john, male
jane, female
gary, male
```

Using pandas, I'd like to fill in the gender column in the first csv using the information from the second csv

I have tried the below:

```
profiles = pandas.read_csv('profiles.csv')
name_gender = pandas.read_csv('name_and_gender.csv')
gender_check = profiles['first_name'].isin(name_gender['first_name'])
profiles['gender'] = name_gender[gender_check]
```

but I get the error:
`pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_csv` and `df.merge`:

```
In [3020]: profiles = pd.read_csv('profiles.csv')
In [3022]: gender = pd.read_csv('name_gender.csv')

In [3037]: res = profiles.merge(gender, on='first_name').drop(' gender', 1).rename(columns={' last_name_x': 'last_name', ' last_name_y':'gender'}) 

In [3038]: res 
Out[3038]: 
  first_name last_name   gender
0       john     smith     male
1       jane     belle   female
2      peter    parker     male
```

Comment: This is really helpful and I did get this to work previously. However, could you recommend a solution using boolean indexing? Reason is that I would like to apply similar logic to other less straightforward cases. Thanks!